# Can the Dispel Magic spell end the spell effect of a spell that already ended?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, duration

I realized I had this question at the very end of answering the following:

- [Does the blindness inflicted by the Wall of Light spell last for 1 minute even if concentration on the spell ends?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/183385)

So I'll just use the example there, *wall of light* for my example here.

Say *wall of light* is cast on somebody, they are blinded for 1 minute, but then the caster of *wall of light* drops their concentration on the spell while their target remains blinded. Can that target then be targeted with *dispel magic*? The *dispel magic* spell states:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

And, to me, there *is* a magic effect in range: the blinded effect from *wall of light* but what is unclear to me is whether that counts as "any spell of [X] level or lower". The spell *already* ended, so what happens in this case?

---

We already have a similar question:

- [Can lethargy from haste spell's ending be dispelled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160797)

But I believe the case of *haste* is a bit exceptional in that its effect *only* occurs once the spell ends and things like this can occur *before* the spell ends and then continue *afterwards*.

Comment: Very relevant, particularly the insight that the rules text doesn't consistently distinguish between "spell" and "spell effect": [Does Feeblemind produce an ongoing magical effect that can be dispelled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146765/does-feeblemind-produce-an-ongoing-magical-effect-that-can-be-dispelled)

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson And related to that case is the following: "[Can a 4th level or higher Dispel Magic dispel the effects of a Duration: Instantaneous spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179235)", I chose *wall of light* precisely because it's duration is *not* instantaneous

Answer (score 5):

In general, a spell effect that can be ended by Dispel Magic is one that is tied to the spell's duration.

Taking an example from another spell - Blindness and Deafness - the spell duration is 1 minute, and the effect itself is tied to the duration of 1 minute.  Therefore, you could dispel it and end the effect.

In the case of Wall of Light, the 1-minute duration of the blindness is an effect of interacting with the spell - and *not* tied to the spell's duration. So dispelling the Wall of Light would not end the effect (For the same reason, dropping concentration also does not end the effect).

For that reason, you cannot dispel the 'blindness' effect of the spell, even if the spell has already ended.  It is an effect that the affected creature has *on* them, and not subject to being dispelled.  While dispel magic can target *spell effects*, its effect is ultimately to only end *spells*.

Comment: "a spell effect that can be ended by Dispel Magic is one that is tied to the spell's duration": is this written somewhere in the manuals or it is deduced by *Dispel Magic*'s description?

Comment: @Eddymage I believe it's deduced from the fact that *dispel magic* only ends spells and not, generally, spell effects, despite the latter being a valid target; as Zibbobz says, if the blindness isn't ended by the spell ending (via concentration ending, the spell running out of time, etc.) as per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/183385), then dispelling *can't* do anything, because *dispel magic* *only* ends spells.

Comment: @CTWind Yes, that is exactly what I was preparing to say.

Comment: @CTWind Yep, the deduction seems reasonable, even if I am not entirely sure of it is correct. As you said  the very first sentence of Dispel magic says "Choose one creature, object, or *magical effect* within range" and the magical effect must come from a spell. Moreover, this distinction betweel "ending a spell" and "ending a spell's effect" leads to something that does not convince me so much (have a look at the comment under Thomas's answer).

Comment: @Eddymage It is a fair concern - it's not entirely clear either if the blindness that is caused by Wall of Light is a 'magical effect' either - or if it is simply the cause of being blinded by light, the same way a Fireball's damage is not a 'magical effect', but the cause of being burned. The latter is pretty clear-cut though, but the former (the Wall of Light blindness effect) does have some room for alternate interpretation.

Comment: @Zibboz, that the blindness does not end when the Wall of Light ends seems to me a pretty good indication that it is normal being blinded from looking at something way to bright. The wall's light is a magical effect, but the blindness is a natural effect from looking at said magical effect.

Answer (score -7):

#### Only if *dispel magic* is cast at 4th level or higher.

*Dispel magic* at 3rd level can only end spells:

> Any **spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

In contrast, *dispel magic* at 4th level or higher ends spell effects:

> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 4th level or higher, you automatically end **the effects of a spell** on the target if the spell’s level is equal to or less than the level of the spell slot you used.

Once the spell has ended, there is no spell to end, so *dispel magic* at 3rd will have no effect. But at 4th level or higher, it can end the *effects* of a spell.

Is it inconsistent? Obviously, but I have ruled it this way in the games I run, and my players have generally preferred it this way: *this makes upcasting the spell better, beyond just the "automatically succeed" effect given by upcasting.*

Keep in mind, it is still up to the DM to decide if a particular effect is a valid target for *dispel magic:* [When can a magical effect be targeted with the dispel magic spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/179646/when-can-a-magical-effect-be-targeted-with-the-dispel-magic-spell/179647#179647)

Comment: Imma try to get ahead of comments being recurred; Disagreement with the internal logic of an answer is best covered via votes. The querent is aware of the disagreeability (I'll leave acknowledging that up to them), so discussion on the consequences is better kept to chat (we have some in general starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57480092#57480092))